# Why won't my callback attach to the end of this promise chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am losing my mind on this one.

All I want to do is chain an array of functions (sync and async), and have a callback when they are all done.

A simple chaining function like this

```
function promise_chain(fns, start) {
    return fns.reduce(function(previous, next) {
        return previous.then(next);
    }, start);
}
```

does work to sequence things, but I cannot for the life of me to get a callback to fire at the *end* of it.  It returns the last in a chain of promises, which should take a `then` callback like any other.  But such a callback gets fired after the first item in the chain.

Here is the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/v6YCL/

It also includes a variant on that chaining function which confirms that the chain does have an end callback:

```
// This version prints the "resolved" message at the end as expected, but
// the message sequence is otherwise the same.
function wtf_promise_chain(fns, start) {
    var _chain = $.Deferred();

    $.when(fns.reduce(function(previous, next) {
        return previous.then(next);
    }, start).
           then(function() {
               message("chain resolved");
               _chain.resolve();
           }));
    return _chain;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a subtle point: when you explicitly return a promise from the `then` callbacks, the promise it returns in turn operates on that value.

To get your desired behavior you would need to write

```
wait(2000)
  .then(function() { starter.resolve(); return chain; })
  .then(function() { message("end, state is: " + chain.state()); });
```

Your current version (copying it here for completeness) reads

```
wait(2000)
  .then(starter.resolve)
  .then(function() { message("end, state is: " + chain.state()); });
```

and since `starter.resolve` returns `starter`, which has obviously just been resolved, the second `.then` causes the final message to be printed immediately.

Comment: Thank God for you, sir.  Now, where in the docs is this stated?  I've been reading them all day.

Comment: @harpo: Actually my first explanation was wrong and misleading, sorry about that! Does the edited answer still leave unanswered questions?

Comment: Okay, that's more like how I thought it worked.  But the result is indeed a pretty subtle difference.